# PhoneGap on Android window.device is undefined

Tags: android, cordova

It seems that the device object is undefined on Android.
It is defined in the simulator, the iOS device & iOS simulator

Obviously I'm checking to see the window.device (and tried all variants of Window.device, window.Device, etc.), and always getting undefined -- but only on a real Android device.
It works fine on all other scenarios.

Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When are you trying to use window.device?

I found that on Android when "ondeviceready" is fired the window.device variable isn't available yet.

So what I did was set a timeout of 1 second after "ondeviceready" is fired and then do all the stuff I want to do.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that even though my plugins folder had the org.apache.cordova.device plugin folder listed, and it was referenced in the config.xml. I still couldn't get it to find window.device (or just device) when onDeviceReady was fired (or anywhere else for that matter)

How I managed to fix it was to run `$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device` again, expecting a 'plug-in already installed' message but it actually installed into the org.apache.cordova.device folder and then everything just worked.

My folder wasn't empty so I'm not sure why this worked and I'm a little concerned about what will happen when I deploy via phonegap-build but using `$ cordova run android`, it now works perfectly.

Comment: This worked for me in an environment where I was building both Windows and Android.  For some reason the plugin was not registered with Android.

Answer (score 3):

Check if this code exists:

```
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

device definitely does not exist on Android until at least several dozen ticks after the `deviceready` is fired, on PhoneGap 1.4.1.