# cordova.plugins giving undefined

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am compiling an ionic-cordova app using the Phonegap Build service. When testing the app on an actual device (and through some debug log messages), I am getting both cordova.plugins and window.cordova.plugins undefined. Strangely, when I compile the app locally (using the Android SDK) and run it on my device, it works fine. The problem only happens with Phonegap Build. I compared the config.xml and they are similar. Here is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.reader491854" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTop" />
    <feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Clipboard">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.verso.cordova.clipboard.Clipboard" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="SocialSharing">
        <param name="android-package" value="nl.xservices.plugins.SocialSharing" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Toast">
        <param name="android-package" value="nl.xservices.plugins.Toast" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="TTS">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.plugin.TTS" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Zip">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Zip" />
    </feature>
    <name>Test Reader</name>
    <description>
        Description here
    </description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">
        Author name
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager" />
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Keyboard">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.ionic.keyboard.IonicKeyboard" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
        <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="IonicKeyboard" />
    </feature>
    <icon src="www/img/logo.png" />
</widget>
```

Any help please?

Comment: When do sou use window.cordova.plugins, I couldn't be set even if deviceready is fired. Here is a reference that points to a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180918/phonegap-on-android-window-device-is-undefined

Answer (score 2):

Ok I solved it this morning. Here is what I did to get it working, for anyone who might be facing a similar problem:

1) The root tag namespace in the config for phonegap build needs to be: xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"

2) Phonegap Build does not use plugins this way, only Phonegap CLI does. My testing was locally using an SDK, and all my plugins were actual classes in the android platform folder. To use Phonegap Build, you don't send your plugins with your source, rather you select the plugins you need from a central repository (two actually). They are: https://build.phonegap.com/plugins and http://plugins.cordova.io/ . Of course, I had to go back and check each of my plugins if they are in those repositories. If not, I had to find an alternative. So now my new config.xml looks like this:

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id="package.id" version="1.1.1">
    <name>Name</name>
    <description>
        Description here
    </description>
    <author email="email@email.com" href="http://www.domain.com">
        Author Name
    </author>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <access origin="*"/>
    <icon src="icon.png"/>

    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true"/>
    <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTop"/>

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.statusbar" version="0.1.4" source="pgb"/>
    <gap:plugin name="com.ionic.keyboard" version="1.0.3" source="pgb"/>
    <gap:plugin name="com.verso.cordova.clipboard" version="0.1.0" source="pgb"/>
    <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" version="4.3.8" source="pgb"/>
    <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.toast" version="2.0.2" source="pgb"/>
    <gap:plugin name="com.wordsbaking.cordova.tts" version="0.2.1" source="plugins.cordova.io"/>
</widget>
```

3) Since the "device" plugin was not included properly, the deviceready event was not firing. I was not properly waiting for this event, and when I did the plugin fixes, it never actually fired, which brings us to the next point.

4) This was the trickiest and took hours. deviceready was sometimes firing, sometimes not. This was solved by having the    to be the last included script in the index.html file. I do not know the reason especially that the cordova docs mention that the deviceready listener behaves differently, in a way that the callback will be called immediately if the event had already fired before adding the listener. Anyway, this solved the trick.

Good luck!